# jQuery img .attr does not work unless window.onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload, attr

I'm trying to assign `.attr` to images using *jQuery*.

```
window.onload = function() {
jQuery('img[src="/i.gif"][alt="info"]').attr({ width: '20px', height: '20px' });
}
```

the above works, however,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('img[src="/i.gif"][alt="info"]').attr({ width: '20px', height: '20px' });
});
```

does not work.

For certain reasons I need the `.attr` to be assigned earlier than `window.onload`. Is there a way to fire the script the moment that the image loads? Basically I want to be able to modify the `.attr` as soon as possible without waiting for `window.onload`.

Comment: Are those attributes gonna be hardcoded? If true why don't you just set them with CSS?

Comment: Sometimes there are reasons for where you have to manually set the attributes, rather than resorting to CSS. One example could be where there is inline !important CSS that you are unable to override.

Comment: I doubt that this will optimize page speed since all this is gonna do is rescale the image, which won't affect the original file size.

Comment: Here's more information for your Fahmi: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/68491/specifying-image-dimensions-to-improve-browser-performance - in the circumstances I'm not sure there is a way to use jQuery to set it up such that the attributes are placed before rendering

Comment: Okay now I understand what you mean by "page speed optimization". Here's my fiddle to illustrate that https://jsfiddle.net/jjkcavwf/

To answer your question, the only solution that I can think of is like this https://paste2.org/VmU7GsFx which is the same as your original solution, but using jQuery syntax.

Comment: If you look carefully with the jsfiddle rendering, using jQuery to insert the width and height does not achieve the same effect of having the width and height attributes directly coded into the img tag. Oh well, perhaps it isn't really possible unless you directly modify the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Thats probably because your image in not loaded yet in DOM ready, so you can either stick to `$(window).load()` or use the image's load() event, as

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('img[src="/i.gif"][alt="info"]').load(function() {
        $(this).attr({ width: '20px', height: '20px' });
    }).each(function() {
        if(this.complete) $(this).load();
    });
});
```

Update::
If source of image is already a set, you need to do an additional check for caches image, as in example above.
Demo [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v1z6ywo7/)

Comment: sadly it didn't work for me, attributes not modified... previously I had searched through stackoverflow and tried a number of `.load` solutions but I couldn't get them to work

Comment: @DavidZ see my updated answer. If the image source is already set then additional check should be done for cached images. I think this is what needs to be done.